# How to set the fully qualified domain name in 12.04?

Tags: resolv.conf

I tried adding

```
dns-domain domain.com
```

to /etc/network/interfaces with no luck. When I run

```
hostname -d
```

I get an empty string

Answer (score 106):

Edit `/etc/hostname` and add your unqualified hostname:

`boson`

Edit `/etc/hosts`:

`sudo vi /etc/hosts`

Add an entry of your desired hostname by replacing `boson.dev.local boson` where `boson.dev.local` is the fully qualified hostname and `boson` is hostname.

`127.0.1.1       boson.dev.local boson`

Restart the hostname service:

```
sudo service hostname restart
```

Test your configuration by opening a terminal and enter the below commands:

- `hostname`

  - This should output `boson`
- `hostname -f`

  - This should output `boson.dev.local`

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's important to note that the first domain in `/etc/hosts` should be your FQDN. I was stuck for quite some time :)

Comment: Thanks @Birla, I was wondering why it wasn't working until I read your comment

Comment: Note that if its not working, try restarting the hostname service (I needed to on 14.04) `sudo service hostname restart`

Comment: I was not able to restart the hostname service (linux mint 18.2). It worked anyway.

Answer (score 17):

The hostname command can be used to set the fully qualified hostname as well. Run it with the name passed as the first argument for that :

```
hostname www.example.com
```

This is only effective till a reboot, though. You can edit `/etc/hostname` for permanent changes.

For changing domainnames, the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/hostname.1.html) recommends the following :

> Note, that only the super-user can change the names.
>
> It  is  not  possible  to  set the FQDN or the DNS domain name with the dnsdomainname command (see THE FQDN below).
>
> The  host  name  is   usually   set   once   at   system   startup   in /etc/init.d/hostname.sh  (normally  by  reading  the contents of a file which contains the host name, e.g.  /etc/hostname).
>
> Usually you can set it in /etc/hosts

Answer (score 11):

Put it in `/etc/hostname`.

For example, my machine is called `hubble`, so in my `/etc/hostname` I have:

```
ashton@hubble:~$ cat /etc/hostname
hubble.mydomain.blah.blah
```

You might need to reboot to get it to show up when you run `uname` though.

Answer (score 3):

​I use domain names to bind my shared storage to my user group TIGERGROUP.  This method allows for the domain name TIGERGROUP to be used as a CIFS share. Think of TIGERGROUP domain name as WORKGROUP domain in windows. If you have a server HOST name (myhost.com) then just add that to then end after the domain name.

example:

```
vi /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       Aspire-Petra16.TIGERGROUP          #i.e. desktop running Petra Mint16
192.168.1.25    sharedstorage-1.local.TIGERGROUP.myhost-name.com   #shared storage media player
```

If I want Samba to also pickup the domain name then I also add it to the `smb.conf`  I don't use samba at home so it is really unnecessary unless you want to be though.

example:

```
vi /etc/samba/smb.conf

#scrolling down the file for workgroup   

# workgroup = WORKGROUP              # pen out the old name with pound key
   **workgroup = TIGERGROUP**         # add the preferred domain name.
```

restart services   (can be done from the GUI or use cmd line.)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Fine! You may follow the instructions given below

```
sudo vim /etc/hostname
```

Then, tap on the I key and use the arrow keys on your keyboard to navigate the text area; Next, enter the hostname of your choice and to save & exit, tap the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, on your keyboard, followed by these keystrokes: <kbd>:</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd>, and, finally, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If it exists, edit the file `/etc/default/dhcpcd` and comment out the `SET_HOSTNAME` directive, by executing:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/dhcpcd
```

Then, insert the # symbol at the beginning of the line that begins with `SET_HOSTNAME=`, as shown, below:

```
#SET_HOSTNAME='yes'
```

Finally, execute:

```
sudo service hostname restart
```

You may also need other reliable source for the complete settings. After you finished the settings you can check the domain details at [WhoisXY.com](http://www.whoisxy.com/) where i checked the whois informations.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me :

- Added the hostname to /etc/hostname file. This set the hostname. but not the FQDN yet.
- Edited the /etc/hosts file

  127.0.0.1 my.fqdn.com localhost everything-else

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to configure the domain to be "*beast.local"* and hostname to be "*davebeast*" such that the fqdn is "*davebeast.beast.local*" for a server who's IP is *192.168.100.100*, this is how i did on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

dokwii@davebeast ~/Videos/zik $ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17
DISTRIB_CODENAME=qiana
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04, Trusty Tahr"

```
1. dokwii@davebeast ~/Videos/zik $ sudo vi /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   davebeast
192.168.100.100 davebeast.beast.local   davebeast

2. sudo vi /etc/hostname
```

davebeast.beast.local

```
3. dokwii@davebeast ~/Videos/zik $ sudo service hostname restart
```

dokwii@davebeast ~/Videos/zik $ hostname -d #domain

**Beast.local**

dokwii@davebeast ~/Videos/zik $ hostname -s #hostname

**davebeast**

dokwii@davebeast ~/Videos/zik $ hostname -f #fqdn

**davebeast.beast.local**