# How to setup SendMail with nginx

Tags: nginx, sendmail

I have a Ubuntu server with nginx I have installed sendmail on it by running

```
apt-get install sendmail
```

I was also able to sendmail using

```
sendmail <my_email_address>
hello
.
```

the mail I received on the specified email was from myusername@ns1234.ip-12-34-23.eu. Here myusername is the username of my ubuntu machine I want to create new mail accounts like info@mydomainname.com contact@mydomainname.com etc. I have read many guides but they assume that the person is running apache2 so the folders were different from what I have

Answer (score 1):

nginx/apache is not particularly relevant to setting up email user ids and servers.

Check the contents of `/etc/mailname`.  This should be where the `nsoo1234.ip-12-34-23.eu` is set.  Change the name to the domain in this file you want to use.

Setting up a mail server for reliable delivery takes a bit of work.  If you are just sending, you can configure your mail server as a smarthost, and use your ISP's relay server.

Incoming mail requires DNS configuration to work correctly.  You may find my post on [Running an Email Server](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/running-an-email-server/) helps.  You should also consider setting up SPF (Sender Policy Framework) record in DNS to discourage use of your domain(s) to send spam.

I prefer to use `exim4` instead of `sendmail`.  Others prefer to use `postfix`.  In most cases any of the three will work as a drop in replacement for the others.  Their construction and configuration are significantly different, but the functionality is the same.

Comment: nano mailname shows mail.mydomain.com should i change it to mydomain.com only ?

Comment: I change it.  You could also use rewrite rules on email being sent to the internet.

Comment: @BillThor Are you SURE sendmail on ubuntu honors `/etc/mailname`? [The file seems to be ignored by sendmail on Debian]

Comment: I use Exim which does honour `/etc/mailname`.  I would expect the sendmail to support it, but it is possible the default configuration does not.  `dpkg-reconfigure` would be the other way I would set the value.  I have seen `/etc/hosts` used as well.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO The simplest way is to change your host FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) to name with `MX` or `A` DNS records in public DNS.

[How to set the fully qualified domain name in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158957/how-to-set-the-fully-qualified-domain-name-in-12-04)