# 14.04 Desktop - how to assign domain to hostname?

Tags: 14.04, networking, dns, desktop-environments, hostname

Situation : we were - and still are partially - on a domain name (`dark.void`) we wish to get rid of! Here is the current content of the different networking configuration files in an attempt to switch to the new `space.opened` domain...

#### /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   supernova.space.opened  supernova

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

*PS: I've added the `supernove.space.opened` to the second line based on [How to set the fully qualified domain name in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158957/how-to-set-the-fully-qualified-domain-name-in-12-04), but to no avail, even after reboot...*

#### /etc/hostname

```
supernova
```

#### /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

*Not used since configured by network-manager...*

#### /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search space.opened space.damned space.warped dark.void dust.hidden
```

*I run bind9 locally to test DNS changes before deploying...*

...

So why `hostname -A` still gives me `supernova.dark.void` instead of `supernova.space.opened`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @adonis that was it, hence my answer (but why didn't you answer it yourself? Had doubt?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... as stated by **adonis** in the comment, I've overlooked the record for the host in the 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa DNS zone! Once corrected, everything looks good :

#### Before...

> nulinflux@supernova:~$ dig -x 192.168.1.254

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
254.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 259200 IN   PTR supernova.dark.void.
```

#### After...

> nulinflux@supernova:~$ dig -x 192.168.1.254

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
254.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 259200 IN   PTR supernova.space.opened.
```

> nulinflux@supernova:~$ hostname -A

```
supernova.space.opened
```

Case closed!